# Default switch in argparse

Tags: python, default

How does **default** switch work in argparse? For example,

**Scenario I**
User inputs the argument through command line. Here the argument is a user defined outfilename (say test.html)

**Scenario II**
User does not input the outfilename argument and expects output to be written to the default filename as coded (out.html) please see below.

I am using the following lines of code to take care of the above two scenarios.

```
parser.add_argument('--out', type=argparse.FileType('w'),nargs='?',default="out.html",help="Output file")
```

---

When I run the script giving user defined filename (test.html) as input command line argument, the script also throws the default filename (out.html) to the screen. Please advise on how to correct it?

Comment: What do you mean, "throws the default file name to the screen". `argparse` isn't going to write anything to standard output during the normal course of parsing command-line arguments. Also, be aware that using `nargs='?'` doesn't make a lot of sense. The default of `out.html` is only used if you don't specify `--out` *at all*; otherwise, the value of the `out` destination will be `None`, not `out.html`.

Comment: Can you give us all your code?, because when I tested, all is ok and it works as you want. code : [code link used](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMOThQMlZrTHd6UU0)